# Having issues splitting/formatting a string into a vector based on multiple criteria

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to split a series of strings that are formatted like the following 2 strings:

```
<verb> sigh <adverb> ; portend like <object> ; die <adverb> ;

<start> The <object> <verb> tonight. ;
```

into a vector in which the first nonlimiter (ex:`"<verb>"`) is the first element of the vector, and then the rest of the string is broken up into elements by the semicolons. So the first example string should be broken up like this when I'm finished:

```
newvec.at(0)= <verb>
newvec.at(1) = sigh <adverb>
newvec.at(2) = portend like <object>
newvect.at(3) = die <adverb>
```

The second example string should result in the vector:

```
newvec.at(0) = <start>
newvec.at(1)=The <object> <verb> tonight.
```

I was provided with the following function to break up strings into vectors using regexs as delimiters and it worked fine when I previously needed it, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it in this case if I even can.

```
/**
 * Splits the input string based on the (string) regular expression.
 *
 * @param input the string to split.
 * @param regex a string for the regular expression to use to split.
 * @param delim if true, then the regex chars will be returned in the split,
 *              if false, the regex chars are removed.
 * @return a vector of strings that is the input string split based on the
 *         given regular expression.
 */
vector<string> split(const string &input, const string &regex, bool delim = true) {
    std::regex re(regex);

    std::sregex_token_iterator first, last;
    if (delim) {
        first = sregex_token_iterator{input.begin(), input.end(), re};
    } else {
        // the -1 removes the delimiter
        first = sregex_token_iterator{input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1};
    }
    return vector<string>(first, last);
}
```

Calling `new_vec = split(ex_string, ";", false)` in my function will split the string into a vector based on the semicolons (and remove the semicolons), but I'm unsure of how to make the first non limiter the first element of the vector. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to use a `std::regex` to do that. `std::istringstream iss(input); std::getline(iss,part,';')` should do the job fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split the whole string into vector by semicolons.
2. Take the first element of the vector and find the position X of the
   first space in it.
3. Create a copy of substring from index 0 to X of the first element of
   the vector and push it to the front of the vector.
4. Delete the first X symbols of the now second element of your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what i tried : it is working but not tidy. you can also use smatch_iterator it will be simple i believe

```
vector<string> splitt(string str) {
    smatch sm;
    vector<string> vec;
    regex re1("([^ ;]*?>)| ; (.*?>)| (.*?>)");
    while(regex_search(str,sm,re1)) {
        for(int i=1;i<sm.size();i++) {
            if(sm[i]!="")
                vec.push_back(sm[i]);
        }
        str=sm.suffix().str();
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that code seems to be working in some cases but not others.

Comment: "<object> waves   ;              big    yellow       flowers      ;           slugs       ; " results in the vector :                                                                               [<object>]                                                                                                   and the string "<start> The   <object>   <verb>   tonight.       ; " results in the vector :   [<start>, The   <object>,   <verb>]

Comment: The string "<verb> sigh <adverb>     ; portend like <object> ; die <adverb>  ;" seems to work perfectly though with the resulting vector : [<verb>, sigh <adverb>, portend like <object>, die <adverb>]

Comment: BJones you can add whatever delimiter you want as per the string in the regex above. In the above case you have ":[" and few other constraints. First define the format of the string clearly, then you can make a proper regex